# Videojs HLS stream, absolute stream time

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js

I need to know at a given time what is the absolute time of a HLS stream, and not the relative time (relative to when I opened the player).

For example

- stream starts at 14:00 (the server starts broadcasting)
- user 1 open videojs at 14:00 => absolute time = 0
- user 2 open videojs at 14:07 => absolute time = 7

I have a snippet that kinds of work but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it or even if it will work reliably in every contexts :

```js
const vhs = player.tech().vhs;
const segments = vhs.playlists.media().segments;
const lastSegment = segments[segments.length - 1];

if (lastSegment && lastSegment.videoTimingInfo) {
  console.log("absolute time is :", lastSegment.videoTimingInfo.baseMediaDecodeTime);
}
```

Any feedback on this would be amazing

Comment: I need to do exactly the same thing with an audio stream to implement a sort of auto sync on multiple devices. Any suggestion? Have you found a better solution?